# How to display new screen when a button is clicked?

Tags: android

I'm writing my first android application and I want to display a result at new screen when a button is clicked . I searched about it , I found that  I need multiple activities or layouts .
But I still don't get what I should do exactly (I haven't developed using Android before). I want to display a totally new screen when a button is clicked , what should I do?

I wish if anyone can tell clear steps to do so.

Comment: For switching between `Activities` use `Intent`. Check [this link][http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/]

Comment: can you give me a link to an example I really dont get this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find information how to achieve that and much more : [Writing your first app - Start another activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use Intent to switch between two Activitys.

```
Intent inn1=getIntent();
inn1=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(inn1);
```

First Create a Simple Activity in android and add a **Button** in the main.xml. Then find the id of the button using `findViewById` method. Then add the **OnClick** Method for the code and put the intent code inside the Onclick Method. And don't forget to do the entry of the class in the **manifest** file.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you correlate this to an .xml layout

```
//Add the variable to avoid any errors
Button goToAnotherClass;

goToAnotherClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anotherclassbutton); //find the button by its assigned id

//Make the button do something:
goToAnotherClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,
                    TheClassIWantToGoTo.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

Watch [this](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=9) video if you are still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you need to look in to Android [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class. One of the many implementations for what you are asking will be using an Activity for each screen of your application.

This is how you start new activity(taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)).

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```